# Recursive Drop Down Image Selection?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a product page layout that allows a customization of a product. Basically, a series of drop downs with each successive drop down populated with options based on what has been selected so far. So like this:

Drop down 1: Product Variant (user selects productvariationb, drop down 2 then is populated with options for productvariationb).

Drop down 2: Product color (user selected productvariationb in drop down 1, now that they select "brown" in drop down 2 the image should change to a brown version of productvariation b).

And so on, with the image changing (and options populating) each time according to what has been selected.

Can I do this with JS and does anyone know of a script similar that I can edit, or what functions of JS I need to look into to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I made you this : http://jsfiddle.net/moeishaa/H9fF2/

It is working with jQuery. Play with it and let me know if this helped :-)

I know it looks very static but you can render the drop-down on page load and populate the options object as well. I am sure you can find plug in and add-ons. This is a very short amount of code and can be customized.

Comment: This is a great start for me. I'm already stuck with it though, trying to make the first box list the sizes (small, med, large) and display a small, med or large image. then the 2nd box will change color of that image. Can you point me?

Comment: It is quite easy to change, look for the first dropdown. In the html I have values : first, second, and third. Change those to small, med, large or whatever you want. Then in the JS the options object has first, second, and third too. Change those to small, med, and large or whatever you named the values. The JS must reflect the values of the options you put in.

Comment: Change the options' texts as you wish, like change 'first option' to whatever you want it to be and so forth. That is just what the user sees and does not affect the functionality

Comment: Alright, got those 2 dropdowns all populated and working great. Now... I need another drop down after these. Can you point me to adding a new one? That should be my last question! :)

Comment: When does the third one show up? After you have selected a value from second drop down?

Comment: Yep, directly after. In fact, it'd be better if they were all there to begin with.. not automagically appearing.

Comment: Can you do me a favor and try and paste what you have (the relevant) parts in jsfiddle.net then save and paste the url here? I think it is better later I just try and work on what you have rather than on my older version. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the best resource for example code would be looking at some JavaScript or JQuery examples on creating expandable menus (more specifically ones that mimic folder structures). They usually operate by decorating an unordered list.

You could create a static unordered list and have the image change based on what item you are hovering over. Alternatively, you could use some AJAX to dynamically populate additional parts of the list as you hover over different levels. Both of those would most likely be easily accomplished with JQuery. Here's a page with some menu examples that might give you some ideas:

[JQuery Navigation Menus](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/36-eye-catching-jquery-navigation-menus/)